# Handling redirections within a div instead of the page for 3D Secure operations

Tags: python, web-applications, 3d-secure

I have a web based client application which heavily uses JavaScript and JQuery. While the client using the application, page content changes dynamically and refreshing the page causes the whole changed content to be lost.

Now, I have to add *3d Secure* payment method to my application. Problem is, (as those who used 3d secure systems might know) after Credit Card number is validated, I was redirected to related bank's 3d security page, where the bank want me to make a validation by entering Credit card's *security code* and the *pin code* sent via SMS to predefined phone number. If related information is right, then bank redirects me to my success url, or fail url if the transaction had failed.

All is nice, but as I mentioned, I can not handle this redirection in my application page. Is it possible to start the process within a div?

I am using python and django as framework, if it would help.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't help, but IMO it's a bad idea to try to do that. You could maybe do it with an `iframe`, but even then, it's probably a bad idea.

And for a very simple reason: when typing their card security code (or whatever), many users will want to check that they are actually on their bank website -- URL, favicon, HTTPS certificate, etc. So don't hide all of this by embedding this in your page.

I usually hate popups, but for me they are totally acceptable in this situation.